# What can I do for a pair of kids who are in China with expired passports, expired visas?

Tags: visas, legal, belize

An old couple in my neighborhood are caring for a pair of kids, their grandchildren. Apparently the intent was for them to travel from their birth country, Belize, and stay in China under their care until adulthood. The parents apparently didn't do the paperwork correctly and it seems that they were on a leisure visa with a 4-month window.

Now, it's been a while after that and both their passports and visas are expired.

Is there anything they can do or try?

Comment: What is the end goal?

Comment: If the goal is still to stay with the grandparents, this belongs on Expatriates Stack Exchange.